# PIL paste image dead center at position

Tags: python, math, python-imaging-library

I'm having a bit of a problem to get an image pasted on the exact wanted position.  The biggest problem is because I'm rotating the image I'm pasting.

```
import math
import sys

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def main(argv):
    img = Image.new("RGB", (
        300, 300), (255, 255, 255))
    dr = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    dr.ellipse((0, 0, 300, 300), fill='white', outline='blue', width=2)
    dr.ellipse((25, 25, 275, 275), fill='white', outline='blue', width=2)
    dr.point((150, 150), fill="red")

    for x in range(6):
        print(x)
        value = (2 * x * math.pi) / 6
        value_x = math.floor(138 * math.cos(value) + 150)
        value_y = math.floor(138 * math.sin(value) + 150)
        print(value_x)
        print(value_y)
        dr.line([150, 150, value_x, value_y], fill='red', width=1, joint=None)
        rotate(str(x), math.ceil(value * (180 / math.pi)), img, value_x, value_y)

    #img.save("output/image.png", "PNG")
    img.show()


def rotate(text: str, degrees, img, x, y):
    ft = ImageFont.truetype('font/Roboto-Regular.ttf', 12)
    tim = Image.new('RGBA', (7*len(str(text)), 12), (100, 100, 100, 100))
    dr = ImageDraw.Draw(tim)
    dr.text([0, 0], text, font=ft, fill='red')
    tim = tim.rotate(360-degrees-90, expand=1)
    #tim.save("output/tim" + str(degrees) + ".png", "PNG")
    img.paste(tim, (x, y), tim)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

or

https://programiz.pro/learn/python/online-ide/EZNBPNRQP1?utm_source=programiz_dot_com_python_compiler_save_button

I can't get this running in the online editor, keeps saying the roboto-regular.ttf file is unknown.  However the output if you run it in an IDE is the following

as you can see in the image, the numbers should be put at the end of the radian line dead center.  I just can't get my offsets right I'm missing some math thing I believe to calculate the correct position.

[image]

I could use any help to try and get the offsets right.  It should have something to do with the size of the temporary image, but even if I take the width and length and divide it by two it still goes wrong :(  I'm missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, it was obvious.  I had to calculate the offset AFTER the rotation, since the rotation expands the image as well

```
import math
import sys

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def main(argv):
    img = Image.new("RGB", (
        300, 300), (255, 255, 255))
    dr = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    dr.ellipse((0, 0, 300, 300), fill='white', outline='blue', width=2)
    dr.ellipse((25, 25, 275, 275), fill='white', outline='blue', width=2)
    dr.point((150, 150), fill="red")

    range_value = 12

    for x in range(range_value):
        value = (2 * x * math.pi) / range_value
        value_x = math.floor(138 * math.cos(value) + 150)
        value_y = math.floor(138 * math.sin(value) + 150)
        #dr.line([150, 150, value_x, value_y], fill='red', width=1, joint=None)
        rotate(str(x), math.ceil(value * (180 / math.pi)), img, value_x, value_y)

    img.save("output/image.png", "PNG")


def rotate(text: str, degrees, img, x, y):
    ft = ImageFont.truetype('font/Roboto-Regular.ttf', 20)
    tim = Image.new('RGBA', (12*len(str(text)), 20), (0, 0, 0, 0))

    dr = ImageDraw.Draw(tim)
    dr.text([0, 0], text, font=ft, fill='blue')
    tim.save("output/tim" + str(text) + ".png", "PNG")
    tim = tim.rotate(360-degrees-90, expand=1)
    w, h = tim.size
    img.paste(tim, (x-math.floor(w/2), y-math.floor(h/2)), tim)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

[image]